# How to execute join query in hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

How to run the join HQL query in Hibernate ? I have inserted the values into one-to-one relationship tables.But before i'm inserting into tables, i need to check if the value is exist is not. If exit i need id for that record.After that i have insert into orderdetails table.

So , i need run the SQL to get the ID from table.

Table : product

```
Product_id
product_name
```

Table : version

```
version_id
product_id
date
```

So i need to find version_id if record exist. I would like to run the SQL : `select version_id from product p,version v where p.product_id=v.product_id and product_name='stackoverflow'`

I've tried this way..

```
Query q=session.createQuery("from Product p,Version v where p.product_id=v.product_id and productname='"+item+"'");
if(query.list().size()>0){
for(Iterator it=query.iterate();it.hasNext();)
{
Version std = ( Version) it.next();
System.out.println("partid: " + std.getversion_id());
V.setversion_id(std.getversion_id());
 }
```

But above code giving error.

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: product_id of: Version [from Product p,Version v where p.product_id=v.product_id and productname='stack']
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.propertyException(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.toType(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.toType(AbstractEntityPersister.java:1465)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.FromElementType.getPropertyType(FromElementType.java:315)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.FromElement.getPropertyType(FromElement.java:487)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.DotNode.getDataType(DotNode.java:611)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.DotNode.prepareLhs(DotNode.java:263)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.DotNode.resolve(DotNode.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.FromReferenceNode.resolve(FromReferenceNode.java:117)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.FromReferenceNode.resolve(FromReferenceNode.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker.resolve(HqlSqlWalker.java:880)
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.expr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:1330)
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.exprOrSubquery(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:4471)
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.comparisonExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3947)
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2047)
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:1972)
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.whereClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:831)
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:617)
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:301)
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:244)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:256)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:187)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:138)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:124)
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:156)
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1770)
    at com.import(CompleteNotice.java:764)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Product Class :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="DBO.PRODUCT")
public class Product{

    private String product_id;
    private String product_name

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="PRODUT_ID")
    public String getProduct_id() {
        return product_id;
    }

    public void setProduct_id(String product_id) {
        this.product_id = product_id;
    }

    @Column(name="PRODUCT_NAME")
    public String getProduct_name() {
        return product_name;
    }

    public void setProduct_name(String product_name) {
        this.product_name = product_name;
    }


}
```

Version :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="DBO.VERSION")
public class Version {

    private int version_id;
    private int product_id;
    private Product product;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="VERSION_ID")
    public int getVersion_id() {
        return version_id;
    }

    public void setVersion_id(int Version_id) {
        this.version_id = version_id;
    }


    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="product_id")
    public Product getProduct() {
        return product;
    }

    public void setProduct(Product product) {
        this.product = product;
    }
```

Please advise how to execute above query in hibernate ?

Comment: In your table, a product can have `one-to-many` versions

Comment: the first thing is that there is a missing qhitespace between product and p.

Comment: Our business version products are different. We have few more tables there to have one-to-many relationship tables for version.Here apply only one-to-one

Comment: What kind of error is thrown?

Comment: could not resolve property: product_id of: Version [from Product p,Version v where p.product_id=v.product_id and productname='stack']

Comment: Has your Version class the property product_id and also a getter and a setter. Ah no it hasnt. Because it has a reference to product you have to say where v.product.id = "p.product.id or something like that

Comment: I have posted the stacktrace.

Comment: Just show also the Version and the Product class, pls.

Comment: @Christian Schack Have updated the product and version class.

Comment: You don't need the int product_id property within you Version class. Because this foreign key relation ship is resolved from hibernate througt the ForeignVersion <-> Product relationship. Thats why the query looks the way i have posted within my answer "v.product.product_id

Comment: Can you pls tell me if i could help you in any way an than vote up me. Especially the -1 looks not good. Of course only if it was helpfull for you. Don't hesitate to continue the discussion. It really seams that it is kust a mapping issue and that there are some ORM <-> Relational Database confusings. Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

At first your class name in this case is Part and not Product.
So you have to use also Part within your query.

Secondly i am not sure if there is a hibernate  id generator which is able to generate 
string sequences so you have to assign an customized id generator.

Furthermore the code you have posted doesn't show the Version class and it's
association to Product or part.

In my opinion and despite of the id problem your query should look like this

```
select v.version_id 
from FeatureVersion v, Part p
where v.product.product_id = p.product_id
and p.product_name='"+item+"
```

When you execute that query. Hibernate creates an instamce of type FeaturedVersion and initializes its properties according to the associated table columns.

Try to avoid using this kind of statements. Use PreparedStatements instead to pass 
parameters to the query and use named parameters or so to assign them to the query.

Try to use property and class names which meet the Java and JavaBeans convention and
Means avoid underscorse and so on. So its simpler to read the query and you avoid frustrating error searches.

Comment: SQL generater generates id for both tables.Because inserting the records perfectly. Now i want to check if particular item alredy exist or not only.

Comment: Assum Product and version as tables. So query is going to be Select v.version_id from Product p,Version v where v.product_id = p.product_id and name='item'.

Comment: Please correct me, if i'm wrong. Because again i'm getting the same error.

Comment: a HQL query differs from SQL in that way that it directly associated with the objects of the Entity classes. Hibernate resolves the mapping to tables and colums within database on it's own So within your query you have to use the classnames and the appropriate property name. References or relationships you resolve using the reference name in this case product followed by a dot and the appropriate proeprty of this class

Answer (score 0):

Your mapping is bad. You don't need `product_id` in `FeatureVersion`

```
@Entity
@Table(name="DBO.PRODUCT")
public class Part { // why not call Product..

    private String product_id;
    private String product_name;
    private FeatureVersion version;    

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="product")
    public FeatureVersion getFeatureVersion(){
        return featureVersion;
    }    
      //put others getters and setter 
 }
```

And in the other class.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="DBO.VERSION")
public class FeatureVersion {

    private int version_id;
    private Product product;

    //add setter and getter that i leave

   @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName= "product_id")
    public Product getProduct() {
        return product;
    }

}
```

And in client code the query string look like:

```
String hql = "FROM Part p fetch join p.version Where p.product_name = :myParam" // this is cause you put it lazy if you don't put anything it will be eager 
session.createQuery(hql).setParameter("myParam", productName).uniqueResult() // or list
```

Some advices:

1)Follow java code conventions for example change `product_name` to `productName` or just `name`.
2) Call classes with the same name in database as convention.

3) For strings i would use `like` clause rather than = if you don't want exact match.